# Change color of a particular RelativeLayout Android

Tags: java, android, colors, android-relativelayout, draw

I have a RelativeLayout:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shape" >
```

The my_shape.xml is this:

```
<stroke 
         android:width="1dp"
         android:color="#FFF"/>
      <solid android:color="#000"/>
```

So, from my activity, i would change the color of this `RelativeLayout`. 
I've tried with

```
RelativeLayout tvCard = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_id);
tvCard.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

N.B. color is an input color!

By this solution, the RelativeLayout is completely draw of red! How can i do to change color of it without change the "stroke color"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to create `ShapeDrawable` in java code.

like this:

```
ShapeDrawable sd1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
sd1.getPaint().setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
sd1.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
sd1.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(1);
// sd1.getPaint().somehow_set_stroke_color?

ShapeDrawable sd2 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
sd2.getPaint().setColor(0xFF000000);
sd2.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
// sd2.getPaint().somehow_set_stroke_color?
// sd2.getPaint().somehow_set_gradient_params?

layers[0] = sd1;
layers[1] = sd2;
LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
tvCard.setBackgroundDrawable(composite);
```

Comment: I've tried with ShapeDrawable but, after this, i see only the border. The entire center block isn't coloured..